# Lord Sri Vishnu is referred to as Murari - who is the demon Mura and and how was he killed?

Tags: ekadashi

I have heard Lord Sri Vishnu being referred as Murari as he killed the asura Mura. While hearing [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTMokvKoqLw) upanyasam on Ekadesi (this is in Tamil and I will try to listen again and mention the moment in mm:ss format), the presenter was saying that the Mura was a asura who was killed by Vishnu indirectly by a women created from Vishnu himself and he quotes this woman's name as Ekadesi.

Can someone put some words with credible reference on that message? If done so, then it would also answer another question [What is the importance of Ekadesi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/what-is-the-importance-of-ekadashi).

Answer (score 2):

There were two Muras lived in the time of Lord Krishna.

1. One Mura wanted to fight with Lord Vishnu and so he went to Vaikunda. At that time, lord was in deep sleep. Mura tried many ways to disturb Lord's sleeping but he failed. Suddenly a woman arose from the body of Vishnu and start fought against Mura ad killed him. Lord Vishnu wake up and appreciated her and blessed her and that day is continued as Ekadasi
2. Another Mura was the commander of the nation where lord Krishna Lived.He was the son of Mother Earth and Lord Vishnu. Lord Krishna killed him for his sins and due to the request of Mother Earth, that day was celebraated as Deepavali

Comment: Actually, in point 2, Mura was the Commander of Narakasura's army. **Narakasura** was the son of Mother Earth and Lord Varaha.

Comment: Lord Varaka is a avatar of Lord Vishnu.......

Comment: But since you used Krsna to differentiate who killed Narakasura, who can use Lord Varaha to be exact. If you see it broadly, it was Vishnu only who both was his father and slayer, but to be precise, we say Krsna and likewise Varaha.

Comment: Narakasura and his followers were assumed to be as demons. It is the job of Lord Krishna's avatar to kill them and save the earth. No matter whether it is Lord Varaka or Lord krishna

Comment: one of the reasons we celebrated deepavali is that Lord Sri krishna killed Narakasura on that day. point 2 should be corrected.@Surya is right.